# Access: Modify values in column of datasheet subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table with the fields: ID, SerialNumber, Capacity, Accuracy.

I display between 1 and 4  records in a datasheet subform based on the serial numbers.

Now I want to display every Capacity

- above 5000kg as tonnes(divide by 1000 and add " t")
- between 5000kg and 0.5kg as kg(keep the number and add " kg")
- Below 0,5kg as grams(multiply by 1000 and add " g")

But, I want all the values to stay in kg in the table. So I only want to change this when I display them.

The last thing I tried was this: I added an extra column named `txt_Capaciteit`, used this as the 'main' column in which the data is stored and then add "kg" in an empty column. But this changes all the columns in `Capaciteit` to the column selected in the column `txt_Capaciteit`.

```
Me.Capaciteit = Me.txt_Capaciteit & " kg"
```

**Edit**:
I also tried to use an expression as control source. By using two if statements, then divide or multiply and at last add "t","kg, or "g". Even though this worked, it made the form very slow and laggy (took 1-2 seconds to load 4 fields)

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many records do you have in this table?

Comment: About 5000, and there wil be added +-10 every week. But as i said, i only display maximum 4 at a time.

Comment: It sounds like something that an Access data macro would be helpful for (add a new field to your table, something like `CapacityAdjusted`, as `Short Text`. Then, have an `After Update` and `After Insert` macro that updates this field using the logic you described. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with Access data macros to provide a full answer (too bad you're not using SQL Server as your backend---I could be of more help there).

Comment: Where did you put your expression when it became slow, in the underlying query or on the form? Try it in the query it will normally perform quicker. If that doesn't work you can use a table to store the text and a multiplier and apply them with a join in the query.

Comment: @Minty I put it in the form since i didn't know how to implement this in a select query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function like this:

```
Public Function FormatWeight(ByVal Value As Currency) As String

    Dim Result  As String

    Select Case Value
        Case Is < 0.5
            Result = Format(Value * 1000, "0 \g")
        Case Is < 5000
            Result = Format(Value, "0.00 \k\g")
        Case Else
            Result = Format(Value / 1000, "0.000 \t")
    End Select

    FormatWeight = Result

End Function
```

Then, to display the weight from kilograms in your form, use for the textbox this *ControlSource*:

```
=FormatWeight([YourWeigthField])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works. However it is stil slow in respons. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: As quick solution, I now add the two value's to the table in kg, and in two extra columns I add them formatted. It's not as clean as when doing it when it opens, but it works for now.